# Insert to oracle db using oledb

Tags: c#, mysql, database, oracle, visual-studio

Hi I'm a student and our professor asked us to do a basic CRUD program. Now, I've done a lot of CRUD programs in C# + mysql, but now our professor asked us to use an oracle db, (forgot what it was. something like 10g XE or something) and said we should use oledb. I've tried to migrate my previous c# + mysql code but apparently it doesn't work. I've done a lot of searching which ultimately led me to this

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string commandText = "insert into Procedures (procedureID,petID,visitDate,procedureType) values(:procedureID,:petID,:visitDate,:procedureType)";
        con = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);    
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(commandText, con);
        con.Open();

        dtpDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dtpDate.CustomFormat = "dd-MMM-yy";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("procedureID", null);
        //i think this line above is the error. correct me if im wrong.
        //but how do you pass a null value to a foreign key in oracle?
        //in mysql i'd just set my primary key to autoincrement and I would
        //just pass a null value and it would automatically set a unique ID
        //but in oracle i cannot find autoincrement and i cannot set my primary
        //key to nullable. is this the error or did I do something else wrong?
        //is oracle's primary key set to autoincrement by default?

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("petID", tbName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("visitDate", dtpDate.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("procedureType", tbProcedure.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Procedures", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Procedures");
        dgvTable.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        con.Dispose();
    }
```

it's giving me a "ORA-01008: not all variables bound" error when I try to insert data.

P.S. I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameters with @ prefix. i.e. @procedureID

Comment: its giving me "ORA-00936 missing expression"

Comment: In oracle you need to create Sequence to set a value which would be  auto incremented. See this for help http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a sequence like below

```
CREATE SEQUENCE procedures_seq
   MINVALUE 1
   START WITH 1
   INCREMENT BY 1
   CACHE 20;
```

Then your commend text will be below:

```
string commandText = "insert into Procedures (procedureID,petID,visitDate,procedureType) values(procedures_seq.NEXTVAL,'" + tbName.Text + "','" + dtpDate.Text + "','" + tbProcedure.Text + "')";
```

Comment: @TGMCians:A question may have multiple asnwers so I posted it without altering original one. Atleast this forum is allowing me to post multiple answers. Why I got votedown? Atleast I am helping him to overcome from his issue, no one else. Really voting down demotivated me.

Comment: Hmm don't worry. I reversed it :)